# Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Meus projetos\teste2.php on line 10, sendo o valor dos arrays um valor de um formulário

Tags: php

Eu preciso escrever uns dados escolhidos pelo usuário, mas quando quando não são escolhidos todos os dados aparece esta mensagem **Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Meus projetos\ on line 10** 
Este é meu código:

**teste.php**

```
<form action="teste.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"> 1 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2"> 2 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3"> 3 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="4" value="4"> 4 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="5" value="5"> 5 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="6" value="6"> 6 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="7" value="7"> 7 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="8" value="8"> 8 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="9" value="9"> 9 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="10" value="10"> 10 <br><br>

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**teste2.php**

```
<?php

$nro_funcoes = 10;

for ($id = 1; $id <= $nro_funcoes; $id++) {
    $nro_funcao[$id] = $id;
}

foreach ($nro_funcao as $func){
    $funcao[$func] = $_POST[$func];
}

$dados = implode(', ',array_filter($funcao));
```

Comment: geralmente o erro: `Undefined offset` acontece qnd vc tenta acessar um valor em um array onde o mesmo não está presente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema**

O valor da checkbox não enviado no POST se não for selecionada.

**Solução**

Verifique se o valor está definido no array $_POST antes de o utilizar.

```
    $nro_funcoes = 10;

    for ($id = 1; $id <= $nro_funcoes; $id++) {
        $nro_funcao[$id] = $id;
    }

    foreach ($nro_funcao as $func) {

        //verificar se está definido

        if (isset($_POST[$func])) {
            $funcao[$func] = $_POST[$func];
        }
    }

    $dados = implode(', ', array_filter($funcao));
```